# If two classes semantically offer the same API, without sharing an interface or parent, can the same code be used on instances of these two classes?

Tags: c#, oop, generics

**Background**

I have a `.xsd` which I'm not in control of, and using Microsoft's `xsd.exe` I generates C# classes to create an XML programatically.

For simplicity sake, a simplified version of the structure is as follow.

- ModelA

  - Many data fields here. Same structure as ModelB.
- ModelB

  - Many data fields here. Same structure as ModelA.
- ModelC

  - Many data fields here. Different underlying structure from other models.

**Problem**

The program `xsd.exe`will create separate classes `ModelA` and `ModelB` (this is perfectly fine, its generation is completely sensible). I don't have much control over these generated classes.

However, when building the XML using these classes, I'd like to not duplicate all the code for accessing the fields as it's quite lengthy, so I'd like to do something like.

```
if(currentNode is ModelA || currentNode is ModelB){
    //call method which has a generic type T, whose constraints are the T is ModelA or ModelB
    //code within method works on both types, avoiding code duplication
}
```

But of course a generic type can only extend one class, or multiple interfaces. So I don't believe this is feasible.

**Solutions I Foresee**

- I duplicate the code. Not nice but I've got type safety.
- I use the `dynamic` keyword. I can use one block of code on the two same classes but I've lost type safety.

Are there any other solutions to this (given that I don't have control over the generated classes, or the original XSD)? I'd like to maintain type safety and not duplicate code.

P.S.

There may be a question of why do I need the type safety if I know the two models in the XSD to be the same. Whilst I'm 99% sure they will always be the same, I'd like the assurance that if in the unlikely situation the XSD has changed, the build server will pick it up.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you wouldn't want to use the same interfaces or parent class? That is the normal way to have assurance about your data.

Comment: Are the generated classes `partial`? If so you could implement an interface containing the common properties.

Comment: @vbnet3d I don't have control over the classes that are generated, `xsd.exe` builds them based on the XSD structure.

Comment: Choose ModelA or ModelB and intanciate 1 of them only no matter if you receive ModelA or ModelB and fill it with reflection

Comment: Add an interface. I run into similar situations all the time with airline (actually GDS) web services that *duplicate* eg the airport type in different places. The easiest solution is to add a partial class for each target that implements the common interface you want

Comment: @Geesh_SO xsd.exe or svcutil.exe generate *partial* classes intentionally, to allow you to implement interfaces and extra methods.

Comment: Going by what Lee and Panagiotis said, it sounds promising. Would I manually have to specify the shared fields (there could be hundreds) or could I create an interface which references the two partial classes? Edit: Now that I think about it more, the latter options seem unlikely and optimistic.

Comment: I looked into this a bit more recently and some of my confusion came from a lack of understanding of partial classes. As suggested above, I think the only way to achieve what I want is to create an interface specifying the fields I expected in these similar models, and a file which is not autogenerated containing partial classes which match up to the partial classes which `xsd.exe` generates and have them implement my new interface. It's a decent chunk of upfront work but definitely worth it for maintaining type-safety and having a sane codebase which doesn't duplicate a lot of code.